# Command: "net stop MySQL57 prompts to "System error 5 has occurred. Access is Denied." Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

When I am trying to stop current MySQL service running on my system it prompts to error message. I have installed "MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client" initially. Then I installed XAMPP on my system. When I try to trigger MySQL, it says that there maybe blocked port. So, I tried to search the service running on the system in the same port (#3306) and tried to stop that. I used the following commands:

```
taskkill /pid 1988
```

1988 is the pid of process using port 3306.

I also used:

```
net stop MySQL57
```

It shows an error:

> System error 5 has  occurred. Access is Denied.

Please help me out with this as I want XAMPP to trigger MySQL service from my system.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in the safemode Because system error 5 is no one who administrator,  can not control by user or the user is not support.

Comment: MySQL service is already running on my system and I need to stop that. However, when I tried to stop that through Windows Task Manager, it says "Access is Denied". When I tried it through command line, it says the same thing. How to get rid of MySQL service?

I need to do that because I want to make my XAMPP server start MySQL which could only be done if MySQL service is not running on the system previously.

I tried through administrator but that does not seems helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's been working for me now!

I tried the following command through administrator and it turn off the mySQL server:

```
net stop MySQL
```

Now I am able to trigger mySQL through XAMPP server as the port has been released.